# tinyint column optimization mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a posts table with columns `id (INT, primary key), name(VARCHAR), status(TINYINT)`. The post's status can be `1, 2, 3 or 4`. And, say, I want to select the posts with status 2. How can I optimize the table to have fast queries, because adding index for status field won't help that much.

I use mysql 5.5. engine can be `innodb` or `myisam`.

Thanks

**update to comments**

As far as I understand how the indices work, is that when we add index it kinda creates a copy of that column but in an ordered way - numerically (or for the text - alphabetically), so it gives a possibility of binary search. So, we can avoid full scan of the table if we need to find some value. But in this case, say I have 100K rows in my table and there are roughly saying - equal amount of rows with statuses `1, 2, 3 and 4`. If I add index for that field, after all it should make a linear search for the rest 25k rows, and if we take into account that adding index slows down insert and update, perhaps it does not worth it.

Query - `SELECT id, name FROM posts WHERE status = 2`

Comment: Why won't adding an index for status field help that much?

Comment: Why adding an index doesn't speed up queries? What type of queries are you doing? Pls, provide an example.

Comment: What are the exact queries that need to be optimized?

Comment: It's pointless to try to offer advice on optimizing queries without knowing the structure of the table(s) and the query.

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius bad  idea this is called a SQL anti pattern. because you place meta data into a table name..

Comment: I would be concerned with the fact that you are wanting to select 25k rows (based on the query shown in your question). How could you possibly display that many? Are there other where conditions you have left out?

Comment: @RaymondNijland well almost every case is different, but sometimes you have to make radical decisions if you need performance. It can be a valid solution, imo :)

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius true but that radical decision should result in harder querys to aggregate the information if you need it, want could also result in slower querys because more joins or an unions is needed (and proberly will use a disk based temporary table to union correctly what will kill the complete MySQL performance)

Answer (score 2):

How well an index works in this case depends on a couple of factors.  Here are three cases where an index would work well (the third thanks to Vatev).

The first is when there are very few records with status 2.  Say, you have a table with a million records and only 100 have status 2 at any given time.  An index will help you find them.

The second is when `status` is a primary key on the table (or at least the first column in a primary key).  This restricts any table scan with `status = 2` to only a portion of the table.  Of course, having a primary key on status makes subsequent updates to the status more expensive, because the data has to be physically re-positioned depending on the value of status.

The third case is when `status` -- or the columns in the index containing `status` -- are a covering index.  That means that all columns needed for the query are in the index, so the engine never has to look up the original data pages.

In general, I advise against indexes on low-cardinality fields.  That is a general rule, but there are some cases where such an index can boost performance.

Comment: The second case also applies to queries using a covering index starting with status.

Comment: @Vatev . . . Excellent point.  I revised the answer to include that.

Comment: True nice explain +1 as a note note, "In general, I advise against indexes on low-cardinality fields. That is a general rule, but there are some cases where such an index can boost performance." aggregate functions is an example that would benfit if you would index status that way a loose index scan can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your application or SQL requirements

You could fetch them in batches DONT use LIMIT because isn't efficient on table with millions off records because it would create a (disk/memory) based temporary table if you query like this.

```
SELECT id, name FROM posts WHERE status = 2 LIMIT 1000000, 1000000
```

if you explain the query above you wil see it's going to scan 2000000 rows and will use a (disk/memory) temporary table, worst case it needs a disk based if the memory is full

Better approach would be to use an position based on your status (make sure to index)

```
SELECT id, name FROM posts WHERE status = 2 and position >= 1 and <= 1000000 
SELECT id, name FROM posts WHERE status = 2 and position >= 1000001  and <= 2000000 
...
...
```

True low-cardinality fields really should not be indexed an better approach would be maybe you can test with LIST partitioning to get more performance but it still needs a full "TABLE (partition)" scan

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d947c/7 for an example and check out the EXPLAIN PARTITIONS statements to see that when you have a WHERE status = 1 only partition_post_status_id_1 will be used.

Or see the covering index approach http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b0d/1 with partitioning

Also querys involving aggregate functions such as SUM() and COUNT() can run parallelized on partitioning to get higher performence

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to really run this type of query often and be fetching the 1/4 of the whole table, I suggest you change the table to use InnoDB engine and the primary key to `(status, id)`:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
( id INT, 
  name VARCHAR (whatever), 
  status TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (status, id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

This way you still have `(id)` as unique but the clustered index (which InnoDB chooses by default to be the primary key) is based firstly on `status` so the data you want with `WHERE status = @X` are stored sequentially on disk.